# Python3 Sanic + ssl certificate

Tags: python-3.x, apache, nginx, webserver, sanic

First of all, I am doing this for the first time and I know that I am lost.

I want to use Python Sanic as the Framework for my website. But I ALSO want to use my SSL certificate and my Domain. The method in the Sanic docs doesn't work. I search  in the web and found that I need nginx or Apache2. But I have no idea what to do then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably best to use Nginx proxy for this. There should soon be a complete guide to this at https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/nginx.html (once docs are rebuilt, soon).

To enable built-in SSL support,

```py
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=443, ssl=dict(
    cert="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem",
    key="/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem",
))
```

Comment: When is the page approximately available?

Comment: The 20.3 release is supposed to come out today but I haven't heard a word from release managers on that. Supposedly docs rebuild will happen if not today then at least in a few days.

Comment: Looks like the release might be delayed but the current docs can be read at https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/blob/master/docs/sanic/nginx.rst